# Tableau - Filter Measure Based on Different Variables of the Same Dimension

Tags: filter, tableau-api, measure

I have the following dimensions: Patients and Collection Type (Blood or Tissue). Measure: Collections.

I am counting how many blood and tissue collections for each patient have been made.
Here is my table: [Collections per Patient by Collection Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8d1a.jpg)

Now I want to filter this table: I want to display only those Patients who have more then 2 Blood Collections and more then 2 Tissue Collections.

So, I want to see only Patient B, D, and E.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways you could accomplish your desired result.  Probably one of the easier ways would be to unpivot your data such that 'blood collections' and 'tissue collections' are separate columns instead of one.  I don't believe Tableau natively supports this while importing a data source currently; however, you can created two additional calculated fields to replicate an unpivot.

Blood Field:

```
IF [Collection_Type] = 'Blood'
THEN [Collection] 
ELSE Null
END
```

Tissue Field:

```
IF [Collection_Type] = 'Tissue'
THEN [Collection] 
ELSE Null
END
```

**EDIT:** Create a Calculated field that contains your desired condition for filtering, Ex.:

```
(SUM([Blood_field]) > 2 AND SUM([Tissue Field]) > 2)
```

Calculated field will evaluate to TRUE or FLASE.  Filter for records for TRUE on this field

Comment: Thank you, tyvich. I've created 2 measures. When I moved the first calculated measure (Blood) in filters, it filtered out all tissue collections. :( Do you have any ideas how I can display both - blood > 2 and tissue > 2?